# Contact Form Vulnerability, Reveals Email Password

Tags: node.js, security, nodemailer, ajaxform, websecurity

I put a contact form on my personal portfolio website, and every couple of weeks, the email address associated with the contact form (which is used nowhere else) gets compromised. Through some means that I'm not aware of, someone is able to gain access to the password (which is used nowhere else) and attempts to log in to my account with it.

When the account is compromised, I find I have three emails from seemingly random addresses with seemingly random, single-word subjects and content.

All passwords are over 10 characters long, using capitals, lowercase, numbers, and symbols.

The website is static, hosted on Netlify. The email is handled by a Node.js microservice hosted on Heroku. Here's my contact form.

```
<form id="contact-form" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" required />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" required />
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="" required />
    <label for="text">Message</label>
    <textarea id="text" name="text" value="" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's the code that handles the contact form:

```
$("#contact-form").submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://my-microservice.herokuapp.com/email",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
      success: function (response) {
        $("#contact-form").html(
          "<div class='form-success'><h2>Your message has been sent! Thanks for getting in touch.</h2></div>"
        );
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $("#contact-form").html(
          "<div class='form-failure'><h2>Uh-oh! Something went horribly wrong. You can email me directly at <a href='mailto: anotheremailaddress@gmail.com'>anotheremailaddress@gmail.com</a></h2></div>"
        );
      },
    });
  });
```

Here's the microservice that handles the email:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://www.my-portfolio-site.com",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.PASSWORD
  }
});

app.post("/email", cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  var mailOptions = {
    from: "my-portfolio-site.com",
    to: process.env.EMAIL,
    subject: "PORTFOLIO MESSAGE",
    text: `from: ${req.body.email}\nsubject: ${req.body.subject}\nmessage:\n\n${req.body.text}`
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.send(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
      res.send(info);
    }
  });
});

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 8000;
}
const listener = app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

Any insight into how my password might be being compromised and how I might stop it would be very much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are any number of vectors that could be causing a compromise, none of which have anything to do with this code.

Comment: So you have made a contact form which public, the contact form sends an email to your email address, and you are getting strange emails?

Comment: Not just getting strange emails. After I get strange emails, I get a notification that a login attempt has been made on the associated email account, using that account's correct password. Somehow the password is being exposed.

Comment: What if your computer is hacked and constantly leaking information, your vacation pictures or digging bitcoin? Would this explain the situation better?

Comment: Probably not. The fact that each time my password is compromised, I have three strange emails being sent from my contact form would indicate that the password is being accessed through some information gained from the form submission. If my computer itself was compromised, I can't imagine suspicious activity would be restricted this way.

Answer (score 0):

on the microservice there is a piece of code that allows CSRF attack thi is the part:

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
```

for more details you can take a look [here](https://fosterelli.co/dangerous-use-of-express-body-parser) or search on google what that extended : true means.